# Need guidance for Ecommerce Database design for multilevel categories

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I am building a basic eCommerce website for my practice and using MySQL DB. I have designed some parts of it. And for the categories table, I designed for up to 3 levels like **Category, subCategory1, subcategory2, subCategory3**. 
As In general, How it looks like is given below.

```
 - Tv
   - Smart Tv
     - Samsuns Smart Tv s45
     - Samsung Smart Tv k7x
   - 3D Tv
     - some product
 - Laptops
   - Intel Core 7
      - Some product
   - Inter Core 5
      - Some product
```

Now my confusion is that, if someone wants that all products should be listed here under the **Tv** table. Means all **Smart Tv, 3D Tv Products** should be listed here. But I can't figure out its DB design.

My database design can only show him all products or the **last level (Smart Tv or 3D Tv or Intel Core 7 or Intel Core 5)** category product but not the mid category products as I mentioned above.

`Laptops -> Intel Core 7 -> Some product`

Do I need to add tags/slug for this purpose or there is another good way to design this.

Comment: Consider the possibility that a TV will be *both* a smart TV and a 3D one.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways that you can use:

**First Method:**

You just need one column to manage categories and subcategories upto `nth level`

```
id
name
parent_id
```

> By default parent_id will be `0` for the main category and then
> parent_id will be taken from the id from the parent category.

You can refer to this link [categories & sub_categories](http://sqllessons.com/categories.html) to understand how to use parent_id in mysql and fetch all possible results.

**Second Method:**

- Create a table `products` with `columns id, name ...` that will contain TV, Smart TV, Samsuns Smart Tv s45 etc.
- Create another table `product_categories` with `columns id, product_id, parent_id`. Using this method you can manage products and categories with ease. Also for cases where same product is part of multiple categories, those you can handle easily without redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do this -

1. Simple way - creating columns into product table like " category, subCategory1, subCategory2, subCategory3... "
2. We need to create 4 tables, category, subCategory1, subCategory2, subCategory3 and the last table which will have all the products listed in this thorough foreign key.

Category table will be foreign key in subCategory1, subCategory1 will be foreign key in subCategory2 , subCategory2 will be foreign key in subCategory3 table and last table will have foreign key pointing to the subCategory3 table.